# Can you help me understand these 2 matlab lines using ~any()

Tags: matlab

I am rewriting a matlab function into a python function but there are 2 lines I am just not sure what it means and how to rewrite.

Here I have a 14 x 7 matrix named `m`,

```
good_freqs = ~any(isnan(m),2);
m(~good_freqs,:)=[];
```

Are these simply just replace NaN cell with 0 values? If `m` has no `NaN`, are these two lines even necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isnan(m)` returning an logical array with logical `0` or `1` saying if there is `NaN` or not. Then you check all rows and see which of them has at least any of the elements set to logical `1` or `true`. That means you check which of the rows have `NaN` elements somewhere. You negate this to get a column vector now, which has logical `0`'s in positions indicating that corresponding row in `m` had `NaN`. Then you basically set all those rows to an empty array.(`~good_freqs` -> only selecting the rows which has `NaN`)

Most probably you can't be sure always whether `m` will have `NaN` or not - (the author or the context in which it was used, this must be the case). But yes, if you are sure that `m` will never have `NaN` then those two lines won't do anything.

From [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, isn't 2 is supposed to be column? And if m has no Nan, good_freqs == m, am I right?

Comment: @J_yang Yes. And regarding the first question of yours. Check the diagram

Comment: 1+ for the illustration.